# How to create a Document Template for "Scanned" PDFs? (Editing isn't necessary.)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-addin

I have a Custom Content Type called "Vendor Invoices". It is based off the "Document" Content Type.

I would like to create a "Document Template" that will support "PDFs", but the PDFs should always be added via an "upload" (since these are Invoices that we will be "receiving", there is no need to actually "Create" one).

So, I don't need to support "New Document" or the "Drag and Drop" "New Document". I simply need the users to "Upload" the documents.

Although, I have created several Columns for this Content Type (Invoice Number, Invoice Date, Vendor Name, etc) that the user will input when uploading the Invoice (PDF), so I WOULD like the "Document Information Panel" to appear.

Is that only possible by using one of the Office document types?

Any thoughts or ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

in order to interact with the document columns from inside PDF Reader ( assuming adobe ), it must first be saved to the library.  when you open the PDF from SharePoint you can then access supported SharePoint integration from the reader file menu, which includes access to document columns.

it wont work directly out of the box for PDF because SharePoint needs to know what to send to the browser so it can open PDF forms. you must update the server DOICON.XML file and check that the PDF section has the correct open control assigned.  for Adobe it is pdffile.opendocument. this will only work is the client side has adobe reader and its browser extensions/add-ons enabled.

To add it as a template you should just be able to upload a PDF and use that URL as the template pointer. However you only use the template from the new drop down in the SharePoint ribbon, not the upload control, which allows you to upload any supported file type.